# WebStorm / Emmet : Как при задании класса выводить атрибут class сразу после имени тега?

Tags: html, вёрстка, webstorm, emmet

Например пишу `a.test`, после нажатия `tab` преобразуется в `<a href="" class="test"></a>`

можно ли и как изменить настройки так, чтобы при разворачивании аббревиатуры с классом, класс вставлялся сразу после имени тега? Т.е. чтобы в приведенном выше примере запись выглядела вот так:

```
<a class="test" href=""></a>
```